# URL amigable con variable id

Tags: .htaccess, url

Tengo el siguiente código pero no hay manera de que funcione. No me lleva a la página que tiene que llevarme. Estoy pasando el id (un numero) para las pruebas pero luego quiero pasar el nombre.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ game.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Me cambia la URL en el navegador pero no me lleva a la página game.php

```
<a href="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Como puedes ver estoy haciendo que la url sea `example.com/10` pero realmente lo que me gustaría es que apareciera el nombre. No me está funcionando nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así debe hacerse:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([[A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ game.php?id=$1
```

Así recibes la variable para hacer la consulta en la base de datos:

```
$nombre=$_GET['id'];
$result = explode('/',$nombre);
$resultado = str_replace("-", " ", $result);
$id = $resultado[0];
```

Y de esta manera colocas los guiones en la URL para luego quitárselos al comprobar en la base de datos el nombre:

```
$nombre = str_replace(" ", "-", $name);
```